# expand web page through left- right instead of up-down

Tags: css, css-float

I aling divs in through right

```
{ float: right;}
```

but end of the page it (when divs become more than 4) the fifth div goes under other divs while page expands to down. I dont want this.  I want height of the page become fixed and web page expand left to right always how can i do this.

Comment: Isn't everthing clear i just need expand whole page to right instead down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `min-width` and `display:table-cell` example in fiddler : http://jsfiddle.net/HarishBoke/c8G7V/

Comment: Your answer just gave me what i need but i didn't why we should use min-width and display properties together.is itsomething special?and thanks for your answer.

Comment: 1) If you use `width` `display:table-cell;` won't apply `min-width` force element to apply minimum width as it's syntax indicate itself
2) `display:table-cell` wraps in row so it do not break to the next row - that's what you needed

Answer (score 0):

On the top level parent element (presumably a 'body' tag) set the [overflow-x](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-x.asp) property, in CSS, to scroll.
Something along the lines of:

```
body{
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

Note that this possible solution may not be pre-IE8 friendly. As far as keeping the page's height fixed, define the height in CSS and set the overflow-y to be hidden. This will hide any elements exceding the parent element's height, rather than stretching the content.

Answer (score 0):

You need a extra div with large width which contains other div's. This will not allow your body container to add new line when running out of space.

HTML:

```
<div id="container" class="clearfix">
    <div id="wrapper" class="clearfix">
        <div id="div1">Div1</div>
        <div id="div2">Div2</div>
        <div id="div3">Div3</div>
        <div id="div4">Div4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    #container {
    height: 275px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    max-height: 275px;
}

#wrapper div {
    float: right;
    border:1px solid black;
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    display:inline-block;
}
.clearfix:after {
   content: " "; /* Older browser do not support empty content */
   visibility: hidden;
   display: block;
   height: 0;
   clear: both;
}
```

To make it more dynamic,you can first calculate the space taken by inner div and then some ettra space on the wrapper div accordingly

Javascript:

```
var width=0;
 $('#wrapper>div').each(function() {
    width =width+parseInt($(this).css('width'));
 });
 wrapperWidth=width+100;
 $('#wrapper').css('width',wrapperWidth);
```

Updated Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ankur1990/mgxk5/3/

Comment: When i add your vode a #div5 it goes down again cause #wrapper width must change after every divs implement. i want a div element which expand automaticly